# wp_insert_post_data() filter for metabox plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a plugin that post some ipsum to a post:

1. Add a metabox with some simple inputs (e.g., # of paragraphs, ipsum type, etc.)
2. When the post is saved, the ipsum is generated and appended to the post content.

I want to use a `wp_insert_post_data()` filter so that I altering the post content instead of saving additional metadata.

How to do this?

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the tutorial request, as asking for recommendations -links, tutorials, plugins- is off-topic. Show the code you're using to create and save the meta box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a matter of doing your `wp_insert_post_data` inside the callback for the action hook `save_post`.

Examples: using meta boxes and `save_post` with [`wp_insert_post`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83717/12615) and with [`wp_update_nav_menu_item`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89665/12615).

Answer (score 1):

imagine we have a metabox (I use OOP approach of [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#oop) link), so we have HTML form element(s) (select, input,...) with **name** property (for example **wporg_field** in the given link example in html() function).

so when we save/update our post, all html form of our metabox(es) submit and we can use `wp_insert_post_data` filter to modify all data of our post including all post information and all metabox(es) data. 
(more info about `wp_insert_post_data` in .../wp-include/post.php line 4388 wordpress 5.9.3)

so I use $postarr to get unchanged post data and use $data to change post title (which is about to insert in DB).

and finally as I want to use metabox sent string as post title and name, I use sanitize_title() to sanitize it into slug.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 );
function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr ) {
    $data['post_title'] = $postarr['meta_field_key'];
    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title']);

    return $data;
}
```